# Does using JSON serializer in kafka streams cause a performance hit compared to AVRO?

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using the following configuration for JSON in my Kafka Streams app,

```
properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,
            Serdes.String().getClass());
properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,
            GenericJSONSerde.class);
properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            com.buy.json.JsonSerializer.class);
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            com.buy.json.JsonDeserializer.class);
properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            com.buy.json.JsonSerializer.class);
```

To measure the performance, I removed all Logic and what ever I receive from IN topic, I am just pushing it to OUT topic. It takes 3 minutes to process 350,000 records

But when I use AVRO, the same streams app process 3 Million records in just 1 Minute. Here is my AVRO configuration,

```
  `properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,
            Serdes.String().getClass());
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,
            GenericAvroSerde.class);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);`
```

The streams app that I am writing should support Both AVRO/JSON. I will decide that while starting the streams app.

My question is: IS using JSON a performance hit in Streams app? Please clarify.

Comment: Apart from my answer , I would recommend you to only stick with AVRO as it is already giving you the JSON like schema representation of your data , along with performance !

Comment: For AVRO, we need to dedicate a separate topic, but in my case in a single topic I need to support multiple formats, thats the main reason we went to JSON. Is there any way to improve the performance. Keeping serializer and deserializer to String and convert into JSON inside streams app? I desperately need to improve the performance. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can have a wrapper class and convert your objects to string in logic layer using jackson or similar library. Publish wrapper object using AVRO and at the consumer side convert string value to object using jackson. For the right conversion you can save  have a class name in wrapper object. Also i would suggest you to post a different question for same .

Comment: If any of the answers gave your answer ,please mark it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note : In case of Confluent's Schema Registry the schema is sent over HTTP first as discussed in comments.**

AVRO is obviously fast because it provide a compact binary data format. There is a concept of dynamic typing and tagging of data during serialization .

In case of AVRO ,the data and schema ( in form of JSON ) is always together ,hence the size become less for data type info during deserialization, better handling of static data types and less code generation.

This is not present in case of JSONSerializer .

Comment: When using the schema registry, though, the schema is sent externally over HTTP, so there is a slight performance degredation for that initial round-trip call.

Comment: @cricket_007 that means the performance result can vary if the load is less ?

Comment: Load is variable, sure. I was only reffering to your comment about the Avro JSON schema is sent together with the message, which is not true when using the Confluent Avro serializers

Answer (score 3):

Compared to AVRO, JSON might be slower in general, because JSON is a text-based format whereas AVRO is a binary format. This is independent of Kafka Streams.

The size of data encoded in JSON is generally larger, which impacts network transmission throughput. AVRO might generally be de-/serialized faster  than JSON.

See the following comparison from 2017 for more information: https://labs.criteo.com/2017/05/serialization/

Comment: during serialization , the text-based format is also converted to binaries. The only difference is that the AVRO is "more" compact in its binary version because the schema of data is also available which leads to less processing and faster results